# igraph network not adding attributes in R

Tags: r, attributes, igraph

I am trying to use `igraph` for the first time, and I am interested in adding certain grouping attributes to some vertex with the intention of using this info to change their color in the graph later. The graph I am trying to make is a network of electrode connections.

I will try to explain the process in detail.

First, I create my network using an incidence matrix:

```
net <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(inc_mat)

> net
IGRAPH 92adce4 UN-B 50 422 -- 
+ attr: type (v/l), name (v/c)
+ edges from 92adce4 (vertex names):
 [1] C3 --C4  C3 --CP1 C3 --CP6 C3 --Cz  C3 --F3  C3 --F4  C3 --FC1 C3 --FC2 C3 --FC5 C3 --Fp1 C3 --Fp2
[12] C3 --Oz  C3 --P3  C3 --P8  C3 --POz C4 --C3  C4 --CP1 C4 --CP2 C4 --CP5 C4 --Cz  C4 --F4  C4 --F7 
[23] C4 --F8  C4 --FC1 C4 --FC2 C4 --FC5 C4 --FC6 C4 --Fp2 C4 --Fz  C4 --P3  C4 --P4  C4 --P7  C4 --P8 
[34] CP1--C3  CP1--CP5 CP1--CP6 CP1--Cz  CP1--F4  CP1--F7  CP1--FC1 CP1--FC2 CP1--FC5 CP1--Fp1 CP1--Fp2
[45] CP1--Oz  CP1--P3  CP1--P7  CP1--POz CP1--Pz  CP2--C3  CP2--C4  CP2--CP2 CP2--CP6 CP2--F4  CP2--F7 
[56] CP2--FC2 CP2--FC6 CP2--Fp1 CP2--Fz  CP2--Oz  CP5--C3  CP5--C4  CP5--CP2 CP5--CP5 CP5--Cz  CP5--F3 
[67] CP5--F4  CP5--F8  CP5--FC2 CP5--FC5 CP5--Fp1 CP5--Fp2 CP5--Oz  CP5--P3  CP5--P7  CP5--P8  CP5--POz
[78] CP6--C3  CP6--CP2 CP6--CP5 CP6--Cz  CP6--F3  CP6--F4  CP6--F7  CP6--FC1 CP6--FC2 CP6--FC6 CP6--Fp1
+ ... omitted several edges
```

From my understanding, this are the edges of my graph, which is ok. Now I am trying to add a grouping attribute to every vertex so I can call later to that attribute for colouring. For instance, C3-C4-Cz I want to call them "cen". To do so, I have another dataframe prepared with the same amount of observations as vertices and in the same order (in this case 50) for this purpose:

```
> head(vertexfam)
    Elec1  Fam
1      C3  cen
2      C4  cen
3     CP1 cenp
4     CP2 cenp
5     CP5 cenp
6     CP6 cenp
```

Now, according to [documentation](http://cneurocvs.rmki.kfki.hu/igraph/doc/R/attributes.html) I understand I can do this straightforwardly attribute by attribute, for example `V(net)[1]$group <- "central"`, and because of it, I have tried to automatise the process.

```
> V(net)
+ 50/50 vertices, named, from 92adce4:
 [1] C3  C4  CP1 CP2 CP5 CP6 Cz  F3  F4  F7  F8  FC1 FC2 FC5 FC6 Fp1 Fp2 Fz  Oz  P3  P4  P7  P8  POz Pz  C3 
[27] C4  CP1 CP2 CP5 CP6 Cz  F3  F4  F7  F8  FC1 FC2 FC5 FC6 Fp1 Fp2 Fz  Oz  P3  P4  P7  P8  POz Pz 

> for (i in 1:nrow(vertexfam)){
+   V(net)[i]$group <- vertexfam$Fam[i]
+ }
```

However, once I check if the attribute has been set, result is not the expected:

```
> V(net)$group[1]
[1] NA
```

Btw, I have also tried to set the attribute one by one and it doesn't seem to be working for me either. I also tried to use base attribute setting mechanism `set_edge_attr(net, name = 'group', index = V(net), value = vertexfam$Fam)` and result is the same. My intention is to do so also with edges, but first I need to figure out what is the error.

Can anyone have any idea or insight why this might be happening or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much in advance for your help!

Comment: you could maybe provide a reproducible example. In general, I think you would make your life easier if you melt the incidence matrix and then use `graph_from_data_frame()`, using the vertices option to pass in the attributes.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I really did not know about that option. As I said, just been "using" the package for 2 days. Tried your suggestion and it is indeed much more straightforward. Thanks very much.